How to block connections to TOR bitcoin nodes?
I'm looking for precisely the opposite.
Any suggestions?
How to block connections to TOR nodes and only accept other nodes?
Can I configure it through the Bitcoin Core Console, in the config file?
Thank you.

No, you can not - Bitcoin uses Tor as a transport, there's no special node type that can be used as a filtering criteria. And even more - Bitcoin is p2p software, and it's lethal to have peer filters for connection! You can filter it later, after the connection is made so you can ensure that p2p mesh is alive - Tor does exactly this: you can choose exit nodes, for example, but you can not choose other things like middle ones or who can connect to your node
